# Multiple TCP port requirement for a client-server relationship

Tags: c#, server, tcp

I designed a basic C# TCP sever that listens on some port. I extended this into 4 other servers that perform very different tasks, but together make up one product. The client needs to connect to each server with the same address, but in this case, 4 ports.

Are there any consequences of this, or is this a good design for a server product that must serve as many clients as possible?

Comment: Are clients required to always connect to all four ports, or can they choose where to connect depending on the services they need? Are the services required to be on the same physical machine, or could they be allocated to different machines?

Comment: The services are all independent, therefore they could be on one machine or several. The client would be required to connect to different services at different times. Example: one for email, one for file sharing, etc.